# Will an iphone in lost mode enable celular data on its own?

Tags: iphone, ios

My iphone has been put into lost mode by some hackers [like this](https://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/4p4miq/iphone_got_hacked_through_icloudfind_my_iphone/?ref=share&ref_source=link).

I have regained access of my iCloud account and removed the lost mode from there however the phone has not updated yet because I always have cellular data disabled(because I dont have a plan for it) and I see that its not connecting to wifi.

I can get 10MB data for a day from the Cell company.

My question is: Will iOS enable Cellular data on its own while in lost mode?

I have an iphone 4 with ios 7

Answer (score 1):

In short - if your device doesn't have cellular, the lost mode transmission won't be received until / unless it rejoins or connects to the internet via WiFi or someone puts in a working SIM chip with compatible data plan.

This link may help you determine the answer to that question.

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19299

In this article, you will see the following. Hopefully this answers your question.

> 7. If you used Lost Mode, when tracking begins, you see your device’s current location, as well as any changes in its location on the map.
>
>    If your device is online [image] when
>      you put it in Lost Mode or lock it, it locks and tracking begins (if
>      applicable). If Location Services is turned off on the device, it’s
>      temporarily turned on to track your device’s location. A confirmation
>      email is sent to your Apple ID email address.
>
>    If your device is offline [image],
>      the passcode lock and tracking (if applicable) take effect the next
>      time it’s online.